# Illustrator: Making areas of color transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hello everyone. I'm a web designer who is brand new to graphic design. I've been experimenting this evening, trying to learn new skills using YouTube tutorials.

I've spent the last 1-2 hours trying to figure out what I'm about to ask you all. I really hope there's an easy answer (I tried erasing and that was just NOT clean).

I want to make the colored ellipses appear only behind the mountains, like a sun. So I need to figure out how to make all of the other colored areas transparent.

Hopefully this question makes sense.

Comment: Have you looked up tutorials on how to create a clipping mask?

Comment: No, I've never heard of it. Will that be required to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Use a clipping mask. Here's how:

- Group the elements which make up the sun.
- With Smart Guides on, draw a Path with the pen tool around the sun and the top of the mountains.
- Using the Selection Tool (V), and holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, select both the new path and the sun group.
- Click *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*
- Then click *Object > Arrange > Send to Back*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that the colors behind an object are not seen there are 2 ways:

1. color the object above
2. delete the portion of the underlying object

The object above is called A and the object below is called B.

**method 1:**

To color object A just select it and give it a color from the *Color Panel* or the *Toolbar*.

**method 2:**

To delete the portion of an object I use the *Shape Builder Tool* (great time saver).
Often I prefer that both objects are shapes and not strokes, in this case I select the stroke/path and I expand it going in the menu `Object -> Expand...`

Then select object A and object B and with the *Shape Builder Tool* [`Shift + M`] select the portion you want to remove.

Then with the *Selection Tool* [`V`] select the portion and delete it [`delete` | `backspace`].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean removing front object from behind one, because it's not possible to transparent front one and still don't see back one.
here my suggestion:

1. Mix up your design
2. Select both objects, then
3. Show up pathfinder from Window menu > Pathfinder
4. And while objects are selected click on "Minus front" (The Red marked option on pathfinder in image below.)

[image]